# SoftKeyboard does not allow keyOutputText and keyIcon on same Key

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to modify the `SoftKeyboard` example (Andriod 3.1 on Moto Xoom) so that I can use an icon on the key and have it output a `unicode` character when that key is pressed.
  Specifically I am trying to have it output a beamed eighth note (musical symbol) which is `unicode \u266B`. 
 Unfortunately I cannot use `keyOutputText` and `keyIcon` on the same key in the `symbols.xml` file which lays out the keys. 
I need `keyIcon` because I could not find a way to change the `Typeface` on the `Keyboard Keys` to one with that character.  I found where I would do it, but its a call to a private method `(.setTypeFace)` buried in `android.jar` (`KeyboardView` if I recall) so I can't.

So I just use an icon to put on the key.  This works fine in combination with `android:codes`, however `android:codes` will not output my `unicode` character when I feed it `android:codes="\\u266B"` which documentation says it should accept.  
 I need `android:keyOutputText="\u266B"` to get the character to actually output into my `EditText`.  So I can make the key display an icon of my character and the `EditText` display the character itself, but not the two together.
  When I try to use the 2 together it compiles and runs just fine, then I hit the shift button on the keyboard to display the symbols and only the numbers 0-9 show up, the rest of the keyboard is just gone.  Now error messages or anything, just gone.  Nowhere does it say these two things are exclusive that I could find, nor does it make any logical sense for them to be.
  **If this is a bug**, I just want to know so I can accept it and stop banging my head against it (a planned fix date would be nice too).  If not, how can I get both the key on the `keyboard` and the `EditText` box to show my beamed eighth note.  I am open to any suggestion or work arounds. 
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a HashMap to map the android:codes to your unicode character.

### In XML :

```
<Key android:codes="719" android:keyIcon="@drawable/zo"/> //use your icon and required code here
```

### In java code:

```
HashMap<String, String> keyCodeMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
keyCodeMap.put("719", ""+'\u0986');
```

---

Then, in the `onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes)` method get the corresponding character using using following code:

```
   String c = keyCodeMap.get(String.valueOf(primaryCode));
```

Use the value of c where you need.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's helpful.  But why would this be preferable over doing it in XML?

Comment: @IgorG. documentation says **keyOutputText** and **keyIcon** can be used together but seems not to work in reality. So, this is a workaround :)  besides, **keyOutputText** directly commits the text to current editor but if you use **android:codes** approach you can format text before commiting it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is really going to help, since it's for `AnySoftKeyboard`, but the problem is the same, so maybe the solution is too?

What solved the problem (for me, creating a layout for ASK) was this:

supply both `keyIcon` and `keyOutputText` AS WELL as `android:codes`, but NO `keyLabel`!
`keyLabel` gets filled (by ASK?) with the first letter of android:codes, but you still see the image and it outputs multi-letter text.

Hope it helps, might be worth a try in any case, I guess.

(Please note: I just found this out and although I could reproduce it, I can't guarantee if it really was this that solved the problem. I honestly think so, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `\u266B` in `android:codes` try the int value of the unicode: `0x266B`.

Then from `onKey` you can convert it back to String using:

```
Character.toString((char)primaryCode)
```